# 15.04: How to enable predictable network interface names by default?

Tags: 15.04

Now that Ubuntu has completed the switch to systemd in 15.04, I want to get rid of /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules and switch to predictable network interface names (a.k.a. biosdevnames). How could I do this?

Comment: solsTiCe answer is wrong. I tested it just now and it's not working. You don't get predictable network name. You still get eth0, eth1 etc that get reset on each boot even if you set GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash net.ifnames=1" and prevent from being generated (sudo ln -s /dev/null /etc/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules)

Answer (score 0):

In **Ubuntu 15.04**'s`systemd`, *predictable interface names* is opt-in by default instead of opt-out. So you have to specify on the kernel command line `net.ifnames=1`

For example, in grub configuration file, `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash net.ifnames=1"
```

You wil also have to remove `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` and to avoid it being regenerated at each boot you need to run

```
sudo ln -s /dev/null /etc/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules
```

Answer (score -1):

Using the new names in `/etc/network/interfaces` seems to be the answer according to this [forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2219332) and this documentation [bug #1312785](https://bugs.launchpad.net/serverguide/+bug/1312785)